# Question About Traffic From Google And GEO Location OF Website

Tags: google, google-search, googlebot

1. I want to know lets say a person who lives in South Wimbledon, UK, runs a website and then outsource the website work (like writing articles and posting and other site management work etc..) to a Philippines based webmaster and he writes posts, publishes so might be his Philippine IP address goes to ping sites or search engines like Google, Bing (if WordPress and sitemap plugin sends the IP). In this scenario question arises:

a. Will Google consider this a South Wimbledon, UK based site?

b. Will Google drive traffic from South Wimbledon city?

Comment: It will always be the IP address of your server since that is where your software lies and works. So any ping or other activity from WP is from your server. The location of the server IP is up to your teleco. These activities have nothing to do with locale search. Locale signals come from you when you code your sites HTML and anything you do in Google Webmaster Tools.

Comment: @closetnoc There is still a conflict what you mentioned and what is going around in the web. I have seen live examples, lets say there is a server in US, hosting multiple sites of people living in different countries like Australia, Canada, UK but when a person sitting in Sydney search Google for any specific term then Google primarily just shows search result from Sydney based sites or sites from around the city and if there is not enough result then Google adds result from global search engine (.com) and so on... whereas site is hosted on US server

Comment: @closetnoc Likewise when a person sitting in Ontario searches for the same term he gets the result related to sites belong to his city, state not from US even though site is hosted on US server

So I'm afraid, your explanation is 100% incorrect

2. How does Google come to know that site belongs to a particular city, state, country  whereas there is no address details in the site and all these sites are being hosted on the same US server whereas Google don't consider then US sites.

Comment: Without seeing what you see, I would not be able to comment precisely. Everything I said in my comment is %100 accurate. However, it seems based upon your next two comments that you are experiencing something entirely different from how I understood your question. Google only take locale data from the website or through Google Webmaster Tools. I can theoretically take IP location, but that would be wildly misleading since IP GEO location data is not accurate. It is possible that Google+ can come into play as well. As well, you may be misinterpreting the notion of gTLD and ccTLD.

Comment: gTLDs enjoy better search penetration over ccTLDs and will be available in almost any search. Where ccTLD domains appear tend to appear first in search is based upon search intent or locale clues which will include .com sites. It is not an exclusive or scenario. Where a site is hosted has nothing to do with anything. It really doesn't. Many Chinese companies have chosen to move to .com sites and host their sites in the U.S. or Europe for better search penetration over the ccTLD. These sites can be seen all over the world where as the ccTLD would not be. I would need search examples to comment.

Answer (score 1):

I think I may be able to follow what you are talking about. Based on your question and your comments you seem to be indicating that you are concerned that your website will appear to be a Philippine website as it is being managed by a Philippine webmaster with a Philippine IP address and you are concerned about this by using the examples...

> I have seen live examples, lets say there is a server in US, hosting multiple sites of people living in different countries like Australia, Canada, UK but when a person sitting in Sydney search Google for any specific term then Google primarily just shows search result from Sydney based sites or sites from around the city and if there is not enough result then Google adds result from global search engine (.com) and so on... whereas site is hosted on US server

and

> Likewise when a person sitting in Ontario searches for the same term he gets the result related to sites belong to his city, state not from US even though site is hosted on US server So I'm afraid, your explanation is 100% incorrect 2. How does Google come to know that site belongs to a particular city, state, country whereas there is no address details in the site and all these sites are being hosted on the same US server whereas Google don't consider then US sites.

Where I believe the confusion is coming from is the methods by which Google decides the location relevance of a website.

The location of a website is evaluated by Google using a wide range of key metrics which include the domain name (if there is a ccTLD), keywords within the site itself, any identifiable physical addresses in the site content, language, keywords, etc.

For a very long time now where a website has been hosted has had nothing to do with the geographic targeting of that same site. There are a number of business and government websites for government departments and businesses based in my home state of Victoria, Australia which are in fact hosted in Europe on AWS servers as Amazon only activated its Sydney availability zones a few years ago and the businesses and government departments have not yet transferred to the Sydney availability zone. This means that when you check the EIP records, run traceroutes, etc, the sites all show up as being hosted in Europe, however the sites are assessed by Google as being Australian sites (note that most of them only use .com not .com.au and only the government sites use .gov.au). If you are terribly concerned you can use the `<meta name='coverage' content='USA'>` meta tag to explicitly state that the site is targeted to the US but this should not be strictly necessary as Google should be able to identify based on your content and keywords that your site is a US site.

As for your second query regarding the Philippine webmaster managing your site and Google detecting that Google is unable to monitor connections between users and your site, only the connections that Google makes to your site. As such when the Philippine webmaster connects to your site to make changes Google has no idea and the only place there is any record of this is the IP record in your servers access logs and Apache logs. If you use Google Analytics then Google will detect a connection from the Philippines but it won't matter as it will just appear like any other user accessing your site.

Answer (score 1):

None of this should matter, Imagine a company in the USA which sells into china.

As long as the content is written in Chinese, and caters to the Chinese market it doesn't matter where the guy who made it lives does it? it obvious which place the content is intended for.

Server location doesn't matter either - Otherwise AWS and CDNs wouldn't really work.

The one thing you could do wrong is set your location incorrectly within google search console (aka webmaster tools).

If you are super worried, simply get a rank tracking tool that will show you rankings in different places and test it to see.